# How to avoid visited nodes by Python list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, loops, nodes

I want to print a combination of starting nodes and end nodes without repeating same pair by following code. I have tried by following way. but it didn't avoid visited nodes.

for example if there is (1,2) , (2,1) should not be in the list. if (2,1) printed , (1,2) should not be printed. please help me to solve this issue. I want to do that by without itertools. are there any way to do that inside this loop?

```
startnodes = [0,1,2,3,4]
endnodes = [0,1,2,3,4]

arb =[(x,z)  for x in startnodes for z in endnodes if x!=z]
print(arb)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like creating the undirected arcs between nodes?

Comment: Could you describe the context a little? If startnodes and endnodes are identical and you want all unique combinations you can use `itertools.combinations(startnodes, 2))`

Comment: I want to print the combinations like following. It mean if (1,2) is printed, (2,1) should not be printed.  i want to do that inside this arb line. it mean i want add that line as a constraint

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this,

```
startnodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
endnodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

import itertools

arb = []
for x, y in itertools.product(startnodes, endnodes):
    if x != y and (y, x) not in arb:
        arb.append((x, y))

print(arb)
```

**Output,**

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
import itertools

startnodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
endnodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

combinations = list(itertools.product(startnodes, endnodes))
done = []
results = []
for comb in combinations:
    if comb[0] != comb[1] and sorted(comb) not in done:
        done.append(sorted(comb))
        results.append(comb)
print(results)
```

Another list `done` is used to track which combinations are done. If you don't mind the order, is not necessary, you can use `results` adding sorted combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the list, create a tuple and add it to a `set`, this should remove your duplicates automatically.

```py
startnodes = [0,1,2,3,4]
endnodes = [0,1,2,3,4]

result ={tuple(sorted([x,z]))  for x in startnodes for y in endnodes if x!=y}
print(result)
```